# Unable to Add ppa in my newly installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, ppa, add-apt-repository

I am trying to install `ppa:ondrej/php` on Ubuntu 16.04

When I enter the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

It gives me this message:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ondrej/ubuntu/php'.
ERROR: '~ondrej' user or team does not exist.
```

[image: Error]

Even I am not able to install any PPA.
How do I proceed?

Comment: please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: I have ran sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade command. even reinstalled OS.

Comment: Maybe there was a (temporary?) problem with the internet connection at the Launchpad end or at your end. I checked, the ppa and the team exist at Launchpad.

Comment: @sudodus I have another system installed with Ubuntu14.04 with same internet connection, but that works fine regarding installing ppas, but the system with 16.04 is not working fine.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late but someone might find it helpful: I had this problem when I set `HTTP_PROXY=` but forgot to set `HTTPS_PROXY=`.

Comment: I think this is very important:
 Add the information to pass `-E` to the `sudo` options. So `sudo` preserves the environment of the user (the proxies in specific).

I've got this information from [this stackoverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724224/cant-add-ppa-on-ubuntu-15-10-user-or-team-does-not-exist). It solved the problem I had (same errors as OP).

Comment: Filed a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1735218

Answer (score 3):

I tested in a live Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and I get ppa:ondrej/php without problems.

But there was a warning, that might explain your problem: "add -apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see [github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56) for workaround"

[my comment: Scroll and you will see the following code, that you can try.]

```
apt-get update &&
apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base &&
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 &&
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 &&
apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 &&
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mariadb-10.0 && 
apt-get update && 
apt-get -y upgrade
```

If that does not work, read the link carefully and look for other tips and tricks.

Comment: Again, today i have reinstalled with Ubuntu 15.10. and the problem still exist. didn't find anything to get out of it.
**$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/screenlets  Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~noobslab/ubuntu/screenlets'.  ERROR: '~noobslab' user or team does not exist.**

Comment: The version 15.10 has passed end of life and is no longer supported. It is easier to get help with 16.04.1 LTS. If it is does not work with any ppa, I think there is something wrong with your installed system or with the internet connection. Please test in a live system, booted from an Ubuntu DVD disk or USB pendrive.

Comment: I had a problem with NO_PUBKEY, see this link to solve -> https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, albeit with 17.04, but eventually determined it was actually a CA certificate problem.
[SSL Certificate error when adding PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646147/ssl-certificate-error-when-adding-ppa) has some solutions to this type of problem.

In my case I eventually determined my company had recently switched to an SSL inspect scheme for all external web traffic, and they were were Man-in-the-middleing all https traffic.  They did this by replacing all external server certificates with internally generated ones signed by an internal root signing authority.  For machines that had that internal root certificate already populated it was fine working fine, but since I was doing a fresh install I had to manually add the root signing authorities to my system's ca certificates.

Comment: Exactly this happened to me. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: I had to add our company CA certs as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but with elementary os based on ubuntu 16.04. The problem comes after installing some certificates and did not resolve when I have removed the certificates even with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` . 
The solution I found was to completely remove the ca-certificates and install it again instead of using --reinstall .

```
sudo apt remove --purge ca-certificates
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ca-certificates
```

and because the autoremove removed software-properties-common I have to install it again by typing

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

After all these steps I can add repositories, use git pull and sudo apt update without any problems.

Comment: as I've already mentioned above, that command did not change anything in my case.  I've tried it few times  but no change until I did --purge of the ca-certificates.

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing that worked for me:

Reinstall certificates

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

And if you're behind a proxy, set the proxy.

Installing the repo manually did not work, but reinstalling the certs did.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

actually, you may have problems with config proxy. Try this one:

```
unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Check they have been removed by:

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

Now try add-apt-repository

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because DNS was not working.

Fixed with:

```
echo "" >> "/etc/resolv.conf"
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> "/etc/resolv.conf"
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> "/etc/resolv.conf"
echo "nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888" >> "/etc/resolv.conf"
```